# Change text colors when hovering over another text (NON-UPDATED)

Tags: html, css

**This post is the outdated version of the question i've psoted, ignore this post,it is only here to notify the users who answered**

I'm trying to do the menu bar for my portfolio,but i don't figure out how to change the non-hovered text color when hovering on one of the texts, my english isn't very good, so i did a little example on illustrator.

The first image is what i want to do, and the second one is how it looks right now.

[image: This is what I want to do:]

[image: And this is how it looks:]

here is the code (ignore the logo, it doesn't appear on the code and it needs no change):

HTML:

```
<nav id="menu">

        <ul>
            <li class="boto_menu"><a class="link_menu_works" href="index.html#works">Works</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li class="boto_menu"><a class="link_menu_about" href="index.html#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li class="boto_menu"><a class="link_menu_newsletter" href="index.html#newsletter">Newsletter</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu {
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

.boto_menu {
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
    margin-left:20.4%;
    margin-top: 11px;
    font-family: 'amador';
}
    
.link_menu_works{
    color: #e1a9ff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
}


.link_menu_about{
    color: #e1a9ff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.link_menu_newsletter{
    color: #e1a9ff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Thank you guys for your help! I've been almost a year without coding and i barely remember anything, so your help means a lot! <3

Comment: the duplicate deals with opacity but you can use color instead to get what you want

Comment: Thank you!! that's exacxtly what I was trying to do! I appreciate that :)

Answer (score 0):

add *:hover* after your three classes

```
.link_menu_works:hover {
    color: #e1a9ff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
}


.link_menu_about:hover {
    color: #e1a9ff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.link_menu_newsletter:hover {
    color: #e1a9ff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I have published the question again since I uploaded the incomplete css code, I am sorry for the inconvenience, I hope you can review my new question and help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :hover in your CSS
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

- There is no need to separate classes for every link. Change it to one class

Example

```css
.link_menu {
  color: #e1a9ff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.link_menu:hover {
  color: #c01313;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I have published the question again since I uploaded the incomplete css code, I am sorry for the inconvenience, I hope you can review my new question and help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the separate links you can hover the link container.

```css
:root {
  text-align: center;
}
.links:hover {
  color: green;
}
.links {
  background: lightgrey;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
}
a {
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a>Link1</a>
  <a>Link2</a>
  <a>Link3</a>
</div>
```

#### Update with your new code

```css
.links { 
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  display: flex;    
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 70px;
  padding-top: 10px;   
}

.links a {
  color: #e1a9ff;
  font-family: 'amador';
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;  
  font-size: 2em; 
  text-decoration: none;
}

.links:hover a { 
  color: white; 
}
.link a:hover { 
  color: white; 
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">  
  <div class="links" id="links">
    <a href="#works">Works</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href"#newsletter">Newsletter</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Unless Im understanding OP incorrectly. This is not what they are after. They want to 'null out' the other links. Not underline the current

Comment: @JamesS I remove text-decoration on my answer.

Comment: Hello, I have published the question again since I uploaded the incomplete css code, I am sorry for the inconvenience, I hope you can review my new question and help me with it.

Comment: @Fone I updated my answer. I clean a little up your code

Answer (score 0):

If "li" is an object in the same location, it would be better to put it in one place.

Select the color code for "a" as the color you want to show before "mouse hover".

And if you use the ":hover" code and input the color code to be exposed when "mouse hover",

it will be displayed like the image you attached.

I didn't speak English well, so I used a translator.

Please understand even if the text is not smooth:)

```css
ul,li {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    list-style: 0; 
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu {
    margin: 20px 0 0;
    padding: 25px 0; 
    background: #1a1a1a;
}

#menu ul {
    text-align: center; 
    font-family: 'amador';
}
    
#menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #e1a9ff;
}
#menu ul li a {
    color: #bcbcbc; 
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
    color: #e1a9ff; 
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html#works">Works</a></li> 
            <li><a href="index.html#about">About</a></li> 
            <li><a href="index.html#newsletter">Newsletter</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hello, I have published the question again since I uploaded the incomplete css code, I am sorry for the inconvenience, I hope you can review my new question and help me with it.

Answer (score -1):

Use the :hover selector

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

```
.link_menu_about:hover {
    color: pink;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I have published the question again since I uploaded the incomplete css code, I am sorry for the inconvenience, I hope you can review my new question and help me with it.